# How to get chartjs column chart in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I am working on a project where I need to show multiple charts using ng-repeat and i'am using chartjs.

Can anyone suggest me how to get multiple column chart with ng-repeat.

Comment: Submit your code, even if semifinished, and someone could help you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the angularjs library for `chart.js`, please checkout [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). For an example of it in action, please refer the below example!

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in repeat">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride">
      </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data1" chart-labels="labels1" chart-series="series1">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We can just use a `ng-repeat` and inside we have our chart definitions. This is a very basic example, please let me know if you face any issues implementing!

**DEMO:**

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>